# Advantages to throwing HttpResponseException over other exception types

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api2

I'd like to know which advantages there are to throw [HttpResponseException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httpresponseexception?view=aspnetcore-2.1) over other exception types in WebAPI 2 from a best practice perspective.

It seems that one advantage is that it is easy to include HTTP status code but are there other?

Answer (score 1):

As per docs [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

"For more control over the response, you can also construct the entire response message and include it with the HttpResponseException"

"You can also use HttpResponseException to return an HttpError. This lets you return a strongly-typed model in the normal success case, while still returning HttpError if there is an error"

As far as best practice I suppose it's subjective. However HttpResponseException is specifically designed for returning an Http response. I would personally go with the method that is specific to my use case.